# ¿Cómo abrir un proyecto en consola desde una Applicacion de Windows Forms? C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Lo que quiero realizar es llamar un proyecto que había hecho en consola cuando hago click en un botón de Windows Forms.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de realizar esto?

Comment: Hola.. con llamar te refieres a ejecutarlo?

Comment: Hola Nahuel, qué es lo que has probado hasta ahora? por qué no te ha funcionado? Recuerda que tienes que investigar por tu cuenta e intentar impolementarlo antes de preguntar. Un saludo

Comment: @NahuelPicca, debes [edit] tu pregunta con lo que has intentado _(código, descripción de errores, mejor descripción del requerimiento/problema/etc)_ para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Todos los proyectos que estuve viendo eran diferente a lo que quiero realizar. Estos casos siempre ejecutaba un proyecto en consola desde el archivo Program.cs. Y lo que necesito es que dentro de un proyecto en **Windows Forms**, me llame a un proyecto en **consola**.

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar. Quieres ejecutar un programa desde tu programa?

Comment: Claro claro eso mismo quiero realizar.

Comment: ¿Quieres llamar el ejecutable de tu proyecto de consola desde el boton de tu aplicacion? o quieres intentar otra cosa?

Comment: Si si eso mismo. Desde mi **Aplicacion(Windows Forms)** ejecutar un proyecto en **Consola**.

Comment: Creo que si le sacas una captura a tu solucion de visual studio nos quedaria mas claro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes iniciar el ejecutable compilado de tu proyecto de consola en el evento click del boton mediante:

```
string ruta = @"\Ubicacion del ejecutable\nombreejecutable.exe";
string argumentos = "-arg1 -arg2 /op";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ruta); //Ejecutamos aplicación
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ruta, argumentos); //Ejecutamos Aplicación pasando los parametros deseados
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me sirvió de mucho. Saludos